# How to avoid the DirectX/Vulkan/32-bit selector when starting Hades?

Tags: steam, linux, hades

Whenever I start Hades on Steam it asks whether I want to run the DirectX, Vulkan or 32-bit version. I always use the Vulkan version, and it would be great to not have to select this every time. Is there a launch option or something I can set to always run the Vulkan version?

One solution floating around is to [move away the "x64" folder and rename the "x64Vk" to "x64"](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1145360/discussions/0/2995417278823661342/?ctp=2#c2995422276381349283), but people are reporting issues like the Steam overlay, achievements etc not working. Others are suggesting a launch option of "-vulkan", but that doesn't do anything as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Launch Editor of [SteamEdit](https://steamedit.tg-software.com/) is the only way, as far as I know, and it's limited to Windows/Wine. I can't test, and it's been almost a year since it's last update, so it may be broken/unmaintained now.

What it does is modify a Binary VDF (Valve Data Format) file to replace launch options (create/remove), change the visible game name, it's name used for sorting, and etc. Based on my own outdated project, the file seems to be `appcache/appinfo.vdf`.

It would be possible to modify this manually, but it would be hard because the file is updated when there's an update to an app/game and destroys the customization. It's also difficult because of lack of documentation of the BVDF file format, and outdated/broken-by-design parsers, along with next to no serialization code.